# ¿Qué esta haciendo esta función? (jQuery, JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery

me ayudan indicándome que se estaría haciendo en estas lineas de código?

```
miTest.common = miTest.prototype = {
        enable: function (element){
            $(element).prop("disabled","");
        },
```

Desde ya, muchas gracias!

Comment: Probaste ver en  consola? `console.log(element);`

Comment: Hola Narciso, no puedo porque solamente tengo los scripts para trabajar, no dispongo del html donde se generan los elementos.

Comment: Es exactamente por eso que se usa la consola. Simplemente abre la consola en el navegador

Comment: console.log(element)
VM1011:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: element is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13